# Buddypress edit profile sequential order

Tags: php, buddypress

I have setup Buddypress to have 3 field groups.  While the user is on the front end editing their profile, I would like it if when they hit Save that it automatically progresses to the next field group.

So for example I am editing my profile for field group 1 and hit save, it takes me to field group 2 so I can edit that without having to click the nav label for the field.

Because this is a form with method="post" I assumed it would be as easy as checking for a post value.  The problem is when I edit the profile and hit save there is not post data.  Im using this just for troubleshooting (note these return empty even after I save):

```
//Next step progression
//Check the field group
echo bp_get_current_profile_group_id();
if(bp_get_current_profile_group_id() == 1) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_GET);
    echo '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    echo '</pre>';
    if(isset($_POST['_wpnonce'])){ ?>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            alert('Saved');
        });
        </script>
    <?php }
} elseif(bp_get_current_profile_group_id() == 2) {

}
```

After digging a little deeper I see the form action is this: `<?php bp_the_profile_group_edit_form_action(); ?>` which calls the function `<?php bp_get_the_profile_group_edit_form_action(); ?>`

I see I can add a filter/action from [how this function is documented](http://hookr.io/filters/bp_get_the_profile_group_edit_form_action/) but I can not seem to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this hook:

```
do_action( 'xprofile_updated_profile', bp_displayed_user_id(), $posted_field_ids, $errors, $old_values, $new_values );
```

Found in `buddypress\bp-xprofile\bp-xprofile-screens.php`

You'll need to write your own feedback message and check the `$posted_field_ids` to figure out which group the user was editing.

Comment: This definitely got me to my answer. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to shanebp I was able to find the right hook and get a working solution like this:

in buddypress/members/single/profile/edit.php  I added this inside the form tag:

```
<input type="hidden" name="group_id" id="groupd_id" value="<?php echo bp_get_current_profile_group_id(); ?>" />
```

Then in my functions I did this which isnt the most dynamic but got me where I needed to go in case anyone else finds this:

```
function update_xprofile_group_progressions($user_id) {
    if (!empty($user_id)) {
        if(isset($_POST['group_id']) && $_POST['group_id'] == 1){
            $url = home_url() . '/all-members/' . bp_core_get_username($user_id) . '/profile/edit/group/2/';
            wp_redirect($url);
            exit;

        } elseif(isset($_POST['group_id']) && $_POST['group_id'] == 2){
            $url = home_url() . '/all-members/' . bp_core_get_username($user_id) . '/profile/edit/group/4/';
            wp_redirect($url);
            exit;

        } 
    }
}
add_action('xprofile_updated_profile', 'update_xprofile_group_progressions', 0, 1);
```

Comment: You should definitely check for errors before redirecting. And you could use bp_core_redirect() instead of wp_redirect - has some advantages.